# User not in group despite /etc/group contents

Tags: permissions, users, groups

I added a new group (call it newgroup)

```
sudo groupadd newgroup
```

I then added my existing user (call him myuser) to newgroup

```
sudo usermod -a -G newgroup myuser
```

I log out and back in, and I check /etc/groups

```
$ less /etc/group | grep newgroup
newgroup:x:1001:myuser
```

So far, so good. However, I also have a new directory (call it newdir) with permissions `drwxrwsr-x` owner is `root` and group is `newgroup`. When I try to create a file in newdir as myuser, I get permission denied.

So I do an id check

```
$ id
uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),118(lpadmin),128(sambashare),131(libvirt)
```

I'm not a part of newgroup. I also try `groups` just to be sure

```
$ groups
myuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare libvirt
```

So what did I do wrong? Why is myuser a member of `newgroup` according to `/etc/group` but not anywhere else in the system?

***Edit:*** The question linked to by muru referred to users that had not been logged out and logged back in. Therefore, rebooting resolved the problem. Coincidentally, rebooting solved my problem as well, but I was under the impression that logging a user out and back in would complete new group assignements.

Comment: Does `newgroup newgrp` work?

Comment: I know this sounds silly, but are you sure you logged out completely... not just locked the screen? run `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart` or reboot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Peculiar permissions/group trouble](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274131/peculiar-permissions-group-trouble)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding user to a group - Why had to reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69221/adding-user-to-a-group-why-had-to-reboot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restarting solved the problem. I logged out and back in twice (the second time just to be sure I hadn't screwed something up somehow), but it seems to take a reboot for the new group association to take effect.

Sorry for the wild goose chase everyone. Is this something particular to Ubuntu (or Ubuntu Mate or 18.04)? I don't seem to remember having to fully reboot to associate users with groups before. I thought you just had to log out and back in if the user you were assigning was currently logged in.